# How to insert a label on a image in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am new to kivy. I have chosen a background image and i want to insert a label on it. But it shows like this.

```
from kivy.app import App  
from kivy.uix.image import Image 
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self): 
        self.box = BoxLayout()
        self.img = Image(source = 'image4.png')
        self.lbl = Label(text = "Total_Wealth")

        self.box.add_widget(self.img)
        self.box.add_widget(self.lbl)

        return self.box

[![enter image description here][1]][1]MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BoxLayout` automatically stacks the `widgets`.

If you want to put `Label` on top of the `image`, you can use `FloatLayout` for more control on the placement of the `widgets`